# On the associated prime ideals of quotient module

Tags: commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring and $M$ an $R$-module. If  $Ass(M)$ is a finite set and $x\in R$ is a non-zerodivisor on $M$, what can we say about $Ass(M/xM)$? Is the set $Ass(M/xM)$ still finite?